I already cleared all entities with a constraint key within the same transaction, but I'm getting a constraint key error
This is the code for clearing my user.
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long userId) {
        courseRepository.findAllByManagerId(userId).forEach(course -> {
            courseService.delete(userId, course.getId());
        });

        managerRepository.deleteById(userId);
        sessionManager.removeSession();
    }

Here is the delete code for the courseService. (Transactional annotation for this code is in my class)
    @Override
    public void delete(Long managerId, Long courseId) {
        if(activeAttendanceService.isSessionActivatedByCourseId(courseId)){
            throw new ActivatedSessionExistsException("Session is activated");
        }

        Course course = courseRepository.findById(courseId).
                orElseThrow(() -> new CourseNotFoundException("Course not found"));

        if (!course.getManager().getId().equals(managerId)) {
            throw new UnauthorizedManagerException("Manager not authorized");
        }
        List<Session> sessions = sessionRepository.findAllByCourseId(courseId);
        attendanceRepository.deleteAllBySessionIds(sessions.stream().map(Session::getId).toList());
        sessionRepository.deleteAllByCourseId(courseId);
        attendeeRepository.deleteAllByCourseId(courseId);
        courseRepository.delete(course);
    }

I've found that clearing a single course works fine.
However, clearing all courses associated with user and attempting to clear user fails with a constraint key reference error.
So I added EntityManager.flush to the code that clears user, and it worked.
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Long userId) {
        courseRepository.findAllByManagerId(userId).forEach(course -> {
            courseService.delete(userId, course.getId());
            entityManager.flush();
        });

        managerRepository.deleteById(userId);
        sessionManager.removeSession();
    }

I don't know why this is happening and would like to fix it without entityManager.flush(). I would like to ask for help.
